# Recursively drilling down the Nokogiri Tree

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, drilldown

I want to drill down the tree, and store all the levels:

```
search_q = Regex.new("Some search regex here")
#something like: page.search('body').first.children.select {|x| x.text[search_q]}.first.children.select {|x| x.text[search_q]}.first......ad infinitum.
```

I've done a hack:

```
arbitrarily_long_number = 100
drill = []
(0..arbitrarily_long_number).collect do |n|
  begin
    drill << eval("page.search('body')"+".first.children.select {|x| x.text[search_q]}" * n)
  rescue
    break
  end
end
```

The problem is that this drills only through the "first" selection. Is there a way to make it drill through every node? I'm thinking of some sort of inject function, but I still haven't wrapped my head around it. Any help would be appreciated.

Output:

```
pp drill[-4]
puts
pp drill[-3]
puts
pp drill[-2]
#=>[#(Element:0x3fc2324522b4 {
   name = "u",
   children = [
     #(Element:0x3fc232060b60 {
       name = "span",
       attributes = [
         #(Attr:0x3fc2320603e0 {
           name = "style",
           value = "font-size: large;"
           })],
       children = [ #(Text "Ingredients:")]
       })]
   })]

[#(Element:0x3fc232060b60 {
   name = "span",
   attributes = [
     #(Attr:0x3fc2320603e0 { name = "style", value = "font-size: large;" })],
   children = [ #(Text "Ingredients:")]
   })]

[#(Text "Ingredients:")]
```

Notes:
I'm using the mechanize gem, which leverages off of Nokogiri. 
http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page.html#method-i-search
http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-search

Comment: What does "store all the levels" mean? Show us code where you are using Nokogiri and a sample of your HTML or XML. As is your question doesn't contain enough to work with.

Comment: Just wondering if there's a clean way with inject. I can do a loop of loops, but doesn't sound like the ruby way.

Comment: @theTinMan Does the output clarify things?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are asking. Ideally you would supply a sample of the HTML, what code you want to run, and what output you would like to see.

Answer (score 2):

To me it sounds like you want traverse:

```
doc.traverse do |node|
  drill << node
end
```

Comment: Close, but traverse flattens the node tree

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear.

If, by

> I want to drill down the tree, and store all the levels:

you mean you want to traverse all the nodes, tell Nokogiri to do that.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<a>
  <b>
    <c>1</c>
  </b>
</a>
EOT

doc.search('*').each do |n|
  puts n.name
end
```

Pasting that into IRB and grabbing the output:

```
irb(main):011:0* doc.search('*').each do |n|
irb(main):012:1*   puts n.name
irb(main):013:1> end
a
b
c
```

I used XML, and you're using HTML, but that won't matter. You'll have to change `doc` to `page` to fit Mechanize's way, but that is easy.